# angularjs material design nested list

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to create nested list (tree) in my application exactly like below. Please suggest me how can i create list like this . [image]

Comment: have you tried anything? or in particular, have you tried using the open source library that you are showing the page for that was used to create that page?

Comment: @Claies what's the point of your question?? you have an answer just feel free to offer it, otherwise don't pollute SO. Hint: there is no such directive currently and for the moment it is the biggest issue with Angular Material - no decent side menu

Comment: @Toolkit the point of the question is that this isn't a site where throwing a screenshot up and saying "show me how to make this" is appropriate.  My pointing that out certainly isn't what is "polluting" SO.

Comment: I'm with @Claies on this - that's a totally legit point and it's essential to discourage the lazy entitlement approach so common in other forums (Qlikview springs to mind)

Answer (score 9):

As of Angular 1.2 you can use ng-start/ng-end to create nested trees/iterate over nested lists.

```
<md-list flex>
  <md-list-item style="margin-left: 10px;"ng-repeat-start="item in nestedList">{{item.id}}</md-list-item>
  <md-list-item style="margin-left: 50px;" ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="child in item.children">{{child.id}}</md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

http://codepen.io/jdeyrup/pen/JRPNyW

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as to the last releases of angular material, there is no such directive to make a tree menu like that, you should combine different directive such as the sidebar and the vertical menu.

I used the sidebar in my project:

```
<section class="wrapper" layout="row" flex>
    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z3 background-red" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')">
        <md-toolbar>
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content ng-controller="LeftCtrl">
            <menu></menu>
            <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary" hide-gt-md>
                Close Sidenav Left
            </md-button>
        </md-content>
            <div flex></div>
            <div class="copy">Copyright &copy; 2015</div>
        </md-sidenav>
        <md-content class="wrapper" flex>
        <div class="wrapper ngview-wrapper" layout="column" layout-fill layout-align="top center" ng-view></div>
        <div flex></div>
    </md-content>
</section>
```

You won't need the part that handle opening and closing of the sidebar.
Inside the menu directive you will be able to put everything you want as menu